# Stack Overflow profile page not appears responsive with height (considered) in iMac?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I am using an iMac and when I view my profile, the page doesn't fit the Safari window. A small portion of the page in the bottom stays white. The height of the page could be made responsive so that it completely fits the window.

> [image: The image.]

Comment: Posting a screenshot would be nice.

Comment: Could less data be a reason for this thing. I will attach an image shortly.

Comment: How old is your iMac? The current (and previous, I suspect) generation of iMacs should all have sufficiently large screen resolution to display the site comfortably

Comment: Site is displayed comfortably. But beneath the site some space stays blank on some profile pages.

Comment: as a policy i can't as i have only 1 repo here

Comment: Then link to it and we'll inline it...

Comment: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjxsrq3thri36qf/Screen%20Shot%202012-07-12%20at%205.08.24%20PM.png  now you can see it... I have to use control+ if I want to avoid the white space. Its not responsive.

Comment: It's obvious, you have too few badges, earn more!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your screen shot I see that the problem is not that your resolution is too *low*, but rather it's too *high*. This question is about what happens to the extra pixels. (Reader: if you can't tell, there is a swath of white space below the grey bar; that's what we're talking about.

From what I can see, this is not iMac (or Mac, or browser)-specific; that's just how the site is laid out. If any user makes their font size small enough, they'll see the same thing. The footer is not floated to the bottom of the screen; it's just at the end of the content.

That said, I have to make my font tiny indeed to make it look that way on my (1920x1200) screen. I don't think most people will have seen the layout rendered this way.

Comment: There is a table there, maybe with a fixed number of rows + padding. Not sure, have too many badges...

Comment: Footer is not laid down to the bottom of the page I think. [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/lg63qf5fj9ydo82/Screen%20Shot%202012-07-13%20at%209.24.03%20AM.png this is the case after i pressed cmd+0. that uses the default size.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you're using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> (or, on your Mac, <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd>) to zoom in to get rid of the whitespace. This suggests to me that, being familiar with this browser zoom feature, you may have used it previously and be at a non-standard zoom level.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> will set your browser zoom to the default level.  If this fixes the problem, you're browsing in a zoomed-out format, so the site's existing responsive layout will not work.

I suppose that some effort could be made to make sure that the page works perfectly at all zoom levels, but I'm not sure that it would be worthwhile.

**Update: [Screen shot from OP after <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnTgQ.png) still shows the problem.

Comment: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/lg63qf5fj9ydo82/Screen%20Shot%202012-07-13%20at%209.24.03%20AM.png this is after using cmd-0